# Correct implementation of Ninject filter binding with Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

When binding to a Filter should I use the `BindFilter` extension method included in the `Ninject.Web.WebApi` or the new convention below, or both?

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
      .Filters.Add(new ApiValidationFilter(kernel.Get<IApiAuthenticationService>()));
```

I am using the latter right now but keep getting the error message below.  I didn't get this in my project before the web-api filter addition.

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use the filter binding syntax, but it does make your life easier and it does the right thing.  I would reject the method you're using on the grounds of using kernel.Get alone, that's just bad form.

Comment: Oh, and you have to use the forked version.  Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC, which is the temporary package until Remo updates the official extension (which is still broken with the RTM)

Comment: Yes, use Nuget, but get the Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC package instead of the Ninject.Web.WebApi.  At least until Remo updates the official, then remove the -RC and get the official package

Comment: Ive tried this and it's still not working within RequestScope.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had to resort to.

```
            var apiRepository = new ApiRepository(new DatabaseFactory());
            var apiAuthenticationService = new ApiAuthenticationService(apiRepository, new UnitOfWork(new DatabaseFactory()), new ValidationProvider(null));
```